# Decoding string from html webpage with lxml

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, lxml

the input string is like:

```
“ hello world ” with double quotes
```

i use

```
Htmlpage=parse(htmlwebpage) from lxml
```

the output string i get is in the form:

```
' â\x80\x9c hello world \xa0 '
```

instead of

```
'"Hello world"'
```

i am on windows 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some solutions:

i found the webpage format using:

```
webpage.headers.get_content_charset()
```

i specified the parser format in the parse function like:

```
EncodeFormat=lxml.html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
```

then

```
Htmlpage=parse(htmlwebpage,EncodeFormat)
```

i still had an \xa0 in the string i removed with:

```
string.replace('\xa0','')
```